# Why does the compiler reject the declaration of a 2D generic array?

Tags: delphi, generics

I'd like to declare a type like this:

```
type
  TDynMatrix<T> = TArray<TArray<T>>;
```

The compiler rejects this with:

```
[dcc32 Error] E2508 Type parameters not allowed on this type
```

I wondered whether the issue was related to the nesting of generics. But it seems not:

```
type
  TDynArray<T> = TArray<T>;//pointless type I know, but for the sake of the Q
```

also results in the same compiler error.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2508_type_parameters_not_allowed_on_this_type_%28Delphi%29) for the compiler error left me knowing perhaps even less than I knew before I read it:

> **E2508 type parameters not allowed on this type (Delphi)**
>
> When using class references, you cannot use generic classes directly.
>   You need to use a wrapper class to be able to use generics.
>
> ```
> program E2508;
>
> {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
>
> uses
>   SysUtils;
>
> type
>   TMyClass = class
>   end;
>   TMyClassClass<T> = class of TMyClass;
>
> begin
>    Writeln('FAIL - E2508 type parameters not allowed on this type');
> end.
> ```

Can anyone explain why I cannot declare generic types in this way?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: `TDynMatrix<T> = array of array of T;` compiles.

Comment: @LURD Yes, but then I am constrained by old school assignment compatibility. The advantage of `TArray<>` is that you escape that particular tyranny.

Comment: To be honest and blunt, isn't the answer to almost all of the "can anyone explain why I cannot...." questions is that somewhere along the line Borland/Embarcadero chose to implement something in a way that was easy for them (or micro-optimized) and just never revisited the issue (and never will as long as a workaround exists)? Iterating through enumerated types, sets with more than 255 members, using a 64bit int in a for loop... there's lots of these things in the language and you can find a lot of them by searching QC for wontfix or as-designed report closures. :-(

Comment: The answer is simple: you cannot redeclare a generic type as open generic type.

Comment: @Stefan Is that written down anywhere that you know? How do I learn more about this? Do you have any better way to declare my type. Independently I'd reached the workaround suggested by Toon. Can it be done any better?

Comment: I know this because I once tried to redeclare generic types from different units into another unit so you just need to include that unit somewhere (poor mans namespacing ^^) which was not possible. See my answer below for a suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is invalid because you cannot re-declare a generic type as open generic type.

I would declare this as:

```
type
  TDynMatrix<T> = array of TArray<T>;
```

This way you still have compatibility that you probably need: the elements of one dimension to a `TArray<T>`.

So then you can write

```
var
  matrix: TDynMatrix<Integer>;
  values: TArray<Integer>;
....
SetLength(matrix, 2, 2);
values := matrix[0];
values := Copy(matrix[1]);
```

etc.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry no reasons, but this one is not limited to TArray,

Using the following type definitions:

```
TGenClass<T> = class fx: T; end;
TGenArray<T> = array of T;
TGenRecord<T> = record fx: T; end;
TGenProc<T> = procedure(const A: T);
```

I have tried all combinations:

```
TGenClassClass<T> = TGenClass<TGenClass<T>>;
TGenClassArray<T> = TGenClass<TGenArray<T>>;
TGenClassRecord<T> = TGenClass<TGenClass<T>>;
TGenClassProc<T> = TGenClass<TGenClass<T>>;

TGenArrayClass<T> = TGenArray<TGenClass<T>>;
TGenArrayArray<T> = TGenArray<TGenArray<T>>;
TGenArrayRecord<T> = TGenArray<TGenClass<T>>;
TGenArrayProc<T> = TGenArray<TGenClass<T>>;

TGenRecordClass<T> = TGenRecord<TGenClass<T>>;
TGenRecordArray<T> = TGenRecord<TGenArray<T>>;
TGenRecordRecord<T> = TGenRecord<TGenClass<T>>;
TGenRecordProc<T> = TGenRecord<TGenClass<T>>;

TGenProcClass<T> = TGenProc<TGenClass<T>>;
TGenProcArray<T> = TGenProc<TGenArray<T>>;
TGenProcRecord<T> = TGenProc<TGenClass<T>>;
TGenProcProc<T> = TGenClass<TGenProc<T>>;
```

They all fail.

You can declare types with complex type expressions, if those types are not generic themself:

```
TClassClass = TGenClass<TGenClass<Integer>>;
TClassArray = TGenClass<TGenArray<Integer>>;
TClassRecord = TGenClass<TGenClass<Integer>>;
TClassProc = TGenClass<TGenClass<Integer>>;

TArrayClass = TGenArray<TGenClass<Integer>>;
TArrayArray = TGenArray<TGenArray<Integer>>;
TArrayRecord = TGenArray<TGenClass<Integer>>;
TArrayProc = TGenArray<TGenClass<Integer>>;

TRecordClass = TGenRecord<TGenClass<Integer>>;
TRecordArray = TGenRecord<TGenArray<Integer>>;
TRecordRecord = TGenRecord<TGenClass<Integer>>;
TRecordProc = TGenRecord<TGenClass<Integer>>;

TProcClass = TGenProc<TGenClass<Integer>>;
TProcArray = TGenProc<TGenArray<Integer>>;
TProcRecord = TGenProc<TGenClass<Integer>>;
TProcProc = TGenClass<TGenProc<Integer>>;
```

There is a circumvention. You can declare the type within a class with a type parameter.

```
type
  TTheClass<T> = class
  type
    TGenClassClass = TGenClass<TGenClass<T>>;
  end;
```

So you can use `TTheClass<T>.TGenClassClass` as a type.

Comment: That's the conclusion I was leaning towards, but I wondered why this was so.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, inspired by the various comments and answers, this is the code that I believe is the most effective:

```
type
  TDynMatrix<T> = array of TArray<T>;
  TDynMatrix = class
  public
    class function New<T>(const Source: array of TArray<T>): TDynMatrix<T>; static;
  end;

class function TDynMatrix.New<T>(const Source: array of TArray<T>): TDynMatrix<T>;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Source));
  for i := 0 to high(Result) do begin
    Result[i] := Copy(Source[i]);
  end;
end;
```

This allows be to declared variables like this:

```
var
  RealM: TDynMatrix<Real>;
  ComplexM: TDynMatrix<TComplex>;
```

And make new instances like this:

```
RealM := TDynMatrix.New<Real>([TArray<Real>.Create(...)]);
ComplexM := TDynMatrix.New<TComplex>([TArray<TComplex>.Create(...)]);
```

Now, if only the compiler's generic inference capabilities were a little better.